# Time Based Workflow on date field to consider week-days only

Tags: workflow, custom-field, date, email-alert, time-dependent-workflow

Is there an easy way to add functionality to an existing time-workflow rule that doesn't send email alerts at the weekend?

At the moment it send out email alerts when a lead hasn't had any activity on it for 2+ days BUT, if it is created on a Friday the email will still send even if no-one had a chance to look at it as no-one works week-ends!

How do I make it ignore the ones created that day / make the 2 day timer only a WEEKDAY timer? It is currently using the system's 'last modified date' --- Do I need to create another date field instead with a formula?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

LastModifiedDate is a misnomer - it is actually a datetime so you just need to add DATEVALUE() to the last modified date like this:

CASE( 
MOD(DATEVALUE( LastModifiedDate ) +2 - DATE( 1900, 1, 7 ), 7 ), ...

Comment: That's right - DATEVALUE needs to be added to the formula - all works!

Answer (score 3):

You can write a formula to get the day of the week as below. Explained in this [link](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=087300000006tam).

```
CASE(MOD( {!CloseDate} - DATE(1900, 1, 6), 7), 0, "Saturday", 1, "Sunday", 2,"Monday", 3, "Tuesday", 4, "Wednesday", 5, "Thursday", 6,"Friday","")
```

Assuming Saturday and Sunday are the weekends, you can create a formula to check the day of the Last Modified Date by after adding 2 days.

```
AND(
(CASE(MOD( LastModifiedDate +2) - DATE(1900, 1, 6), 7), 0, "Saturday", 1, "Sunday", 2,"Monday", 3, "Tuesday", 4, "Wednesday", 5, "Thursday", 6,"Friday","")<>"Saturday")
,
(CASE(MOD( LastModifiedDate +2) - DATE(1900, 1, 6), 7), 0, "Saturday", 1, "Sunday", 2,"Monday", 3, "Tuesday", 4, "Wednesday", 5, "Thursday", 6,"Friday","")<>"Sunday")
)
```

Comment: Thanks @Saroj! I tried to do the 'text' version like it mentions in the link (i.e. your second example) but I am getting this [error](http://imgur.com/a/ZyyX8) I have chosen the 'Formula' with 'text' return type in a new custom field... thanks